# What should be done when the name of Holy prophet is repeated several times in a khutba?

Tags: fiqh, salawat, khutbah

While in any address by a mufti, the name of Holy Prophet is repeated multiple times? What should the audience do in this situation? Do we offer darood-o-salam every time or not, because while doing so, one can often lose concentration on 
the address.

Answer (score 2):

A Muslim is supposed to ask Allaah to send salaah and salaam upon the Messenger of Allaah when he hears the mention of the Messenger of Allaah. The wisdom appears to be to keep tongues moist with the remembrance of Allaah and his messenger.

It would not befit the spirit of this practice to **reduce** it to a literal meaning, that if the Messenger's name was heard *nine times* therefore Allaah must be asked *nine times* each to send salaah and salaam upon his messenger. Allaah does not need worship; the worshiper needs Allaah.

*Salla Allaahu `alaa muhammadi wasallam.*
May Allaah send peace and blessings upon Muhammad.

*Wallaahu a`lam.*
Allaah is the Knower of All.

I am not a scholar of jurisprudence.

Comment: And yet, you are wise.